# Correspondence between G-covers and grupoid homomorphisms

Tags: representation-theory, covering-spaces, principal-bundles, topological-quantum-field-theory

I have a question concerning this article ([https://math.berkeley.edu/~qchu/TQFT.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eqchu/TQFT.pdf)) about TQFTs and representation theory of finite groups.

In the beginning of the third section, it is stated that, for a finite group $G$, a $G$-cover is the same as a groupoid homomorphism $$\Pi_1(M)\to BG,$$ between the fundamental groupoid of a manifold $M$ and the groupoid consisting of one object whose automorphisms are the elements of $G$.

I would like to get my head around this correspondence, but I don't know much about principal $G$-bundles, so I would appreciate any hints or reference recommendations that would allow me to understand it in further detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the classification of coverings.
It is often given as a statement about the fundamental group, but can be easily generalized to fundamental groupoids.

A detailed exposition in the language of groupoids is available in Ronald Brown's *Topology and Groupoids*.